# Linking OpenCL libraries while compiling C++ code with icpc

Tags: c++, opencl, icc

I am trying to compile a C++ program (that uses OpenCL functions) using Intel ICPC compiler: `icpc mycode.cpp`. I am getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_clBuildProgram", referenced from:
      _main in icpc4lnp65.o
  ..
  ..

  "_clSetKernelArg", referenced from:
      _main in icpc4lnp65.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

For g++ I saw that `-framework OpenCL` argument does the job of linking OpenCL libraries, but I am unable to figure out how to do the linking of OpenCL libraries using ICPC and there is not much documentation on using ICPC with OpenCL.

Comment: What command line are you using? Are you linking against `OpenCL.lib`?

Comment: I tried linking using `icpc -lOpenCL mycode.cpp` but that shows me `ld: library not found for -lOpenCL`.

Comment: Try running the `g++` linker command with `-v`, which should output the linker commandline arguments, and possibly show you the location of the OpenCL library you need to link.